# Is my interpretation of voltage, amperes and ohms correct?

Tags: voltage, resistance, basic, watts

This is probably a very common question, but I feel most metaphors are somewhat simplified and therefore lack accuracy and
I think that makes me unable to fully understand them, but I've looked at it in different terms and came to a visualisation myself. Can anyone tell me if it's a good way of looking at it and where I'm wrong?

Please keep in mind that it's a visualisation, not a metaphor.

I'd imagine an electrical circuit as two basins connected to each other with a pipe.

With a perfect, untouched battery, both basins would be filled halfway with water. There is a one-way valve in the middle of the pipe. The valve can either be completely closed (representing the circuit not completed) or be completely open (representing the circuit is completed.) The voltage would be the angle of the pipe, vertical being a theoretical maximum (remember this isn't a perfect metaphor,) and a horizontal pipe would be a voltage of 0.

The bottom basin would be the -, and the top one would be the + with the angle of the pipe being a visualisation for the potential energy.  The water would want to move through the pipe to the bottom basin with more pressure the steeper the angle. The amperes would be how many liters would be in a section of the pipe at any given moment, visualized as the pipe's width.

Keep in mind this is a visualisation.

Ohms would be the weirdest one to visualize, but hear me out. For ohms we have to change the water into steam. The amount of ohms would be the length of the pipe. The longer the pipe, the more the steam would lose amperes, visualized as water condensing on the inside of the pipe. The longer the pipe, the more water would be lost due to condensation (or in electrical terms, probably heat.) Keep in mind the length of the pipe isn't a metaphor for the length of the wire but rather a visualisation of resistance - a visualisation for how much water/watts would be lost. Watts would just be the amount of water that enters the bottom basin per specified timeframe.

Please tell me the flaws in my interpretation.

Comment: For a **circuit** you need a closed loop, not just one pipe. What do the two basins represent in your analogy? There are so many things wrong here I don't know where to start.

Comment: if you have two batteries connected, then a height difference will not cause electricity to flow, unlike gravity and the two tanks.

Comment: Current, voltage, and resistance are effectively described using branch constituent equations (i.e. Ohm's Law for a resistor), KCL, and KVL. Attempting to apply analogies to these things often ends poorly - rather than trying to visualize it using these poorly-matched analogies, focus on learning the math behind it and allowing a new, electrical-circuits-specific intuition develop instead. With practice, one can eventually look at a circuit and directly visualize currents and voltages without relying on inaccurate mapping to water pipes, steam, etc, and until then, apply equations accurately

Comment: What you describe is an **analogy**, not a visualization, no matter how many times you repeat that claim. A visualization takes something that has data, but is not visual, and makes it visual. E.g., I can draw arrows where an electric field is. What you do is take a completely unrelated phenomenon, and make it represent the phenomenon you want to describe. That's an analogy, not a visualization.

Comment: Other than that, no, electricity doesn't behave like this at all, so this is really working out.

Comment: `Keep in mind this is a visualisation.` - I see nothing that constitutes a visualization. Doesn't a visualization need er... visuals or diagrams or pictures?

Comment: @Andyaka the visualization can be in your head ... usually requires the speaker to possess a mastery of the language

Comment: `The amperes would be how many liters would be in a section of the pipe at any given moment` ... what about a full pipe with a closed valve?

Comment: >>> The water would want to move through the pipe to the bottom basin with more pressure the steeper the angle     $$$$  This is not correct even with water.  It's the difference in heights that determines the relative pressure in your 2 basins. $$$$  If somebody were to drop a brick on your head, would you prefer they do it from 1mm above, or 1 meter????

Comment: What you claim to be "watts" is actually "coloumbs"

Comment: Analogies are meant to simplify a complex subject. But seems like you complicated the subject instead and now you need to fix the understanding of fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

Bluntly, no.

You're OK using the heights of the two basins. Then the difference in voltage between the two basins is just the difference in heights. The angle of the pipe connecting them is irrelevant.

What does matter is the length of the pipe. The inner diameter of the pipe will control the flow rate (which is analogous to current). The behavior of flow vs diameter is actually quite complicated, but you can start by assuming that the smaller the diameter, the lower the flow rate, so resistance is inversely proportional to pipe diameter (in the most general sense) and directly proportional to length of the pipe.

For a given height difference, for a straight pipe the greater the angle of the pipe, the shorter it will be, so the equivalent resistance will be smaller and the flow rate will be greater.

Talking about water in the pipe being treated as steam is way overthinking things.